# Fastest Map Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, kryo

I'm working with a big collection of JSON objects (parsing using the `json-smart`) library.   My processing treats the objects as HashMaps.

While I expected the overhead of parsing JSON to be significant, what I'm finding is when I use Java serialization and the Kryo libraries, the time to deserialize from binary format isn't significantly faster than just parsing the JSON object.

Are there alternate HashMap implementations/serialization I can be using?

Comment: Depends, what do the JSON objects contain?

Comment: I prefer Faster XML Jackson.  So does the Spring Boot gang.  Why not try that?  It's "Faster".  I doubt that libraries will behave significantly different when processing Maps.  Those are going to be O(n) no matter what you do.

Comment: To be clear, this is independent of JSON parsing - except that deserializing from JSON should be significantly slower than deserializing from a binary format.